# is it possible to make comment appear faster in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are some comments in my Excel sheet

Is it possible to make them appear faster when user hovers a mouse pointer over cell? Currently there is a small delay before the comment pop ups, I'd like the comment to appear instantly (as soon as the mouse enters the cell).

I couldn't find such option in GUI, so maybe there is some hacking approach via VBA?

Comment: all I am saying - it takes some time to see the tooltip.. I thought that maybe it is possible to change some config via VBA, in order to show comments instantly.

Comment: oh, I didn't mean the animation of any sort.. sorry if it confused you. In fact - I disabled all animations in office. What's left now - is that once you hover your mouse oven a cell with the red small triangle - the comment tooltip will appear after some time. I have 10 of such cells in a row. It would be a lot easier, if comment appeared instantly, asap user hovers cell with a mouse cursor..

Comment: What about if you just show comments all the time? you can position them so they don't interfere with the view of cells..

Comment: Or [if you really want to get into it](http://www.atlaspm.com/toms-tutorials-for-excel/tomstutorialsforexcel-mousing-over-a-cell-to-run-a-macro/)

Comment: It's better to just leave the commented cell and go back, then it will display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with VBa, and you've already seen there is no option to configure it in Excel.

In regards to VBa, there is no mouseover event or similar for cells. The only way you could do something is to hack it, by adding a control to every cell you want this and create a mouseover event for each control!

[Source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/4456-visual-basic-applications-mouseover-cell.html)

Comment: Without selecting the cell, there is no VBA event. This is the correct answer.